# MouseLeave not firing if a WinForm has only one full-docked ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, dock, mouseleave

I have a Form with only a simple listbox. The listbox is Full-docked and the Form's FormBorderStyle is set to None.

When I attach a MouseLeave event to a form, it does not fire. (It also does not fire MouseMove, MouseHover etc.)

However, if I undock the listbox and resize it so at least a part of the form is visible and if I move mouse over the visible part of the form, all mouse events fire again.

How to get the form to receive mouse events even if it's consisted only of a full-docked listbox?

Thanks

Comment: Can you just attach the events to the listbox instead?

Comment: Clearly you cannot get mouse events for the form when the entire form is covered by another control.  Everything goes to the list box.

Comment: So basically, there's no event bubbleing in WinForms. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldnt fire bacause your mouse didnt enter to form on, it enters on listbox. So you should use MouseLeave event in listbox control

Comment: The reason I haven't attached an event to a listbox is that it may not be a listbox at some other moment. I'll just save a reference to a Control (whichever fills the form) to a form's private variable and attach/detach events to that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. Because the control will handle the events it won't be bypassed to Form.